# Show that the evaluation functional is bounded for absolutely continuous functions under the norm $\sqrt{\lVert f\Vert_2^2+\lVert f'\Vert_2^2}$

Tags: functional-analysis, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ denote the set of functions $f:[0, 1]\to\mathbb R$ that are
absolutely continuous, with $f' ∈ L_2 [0, 1]$ and $f(0) = f(1) = 0$. Define an inner
product on H by $\langle f, g\rangle = \int_0^1 (f(t)g(t) + f'(t)g'(t))dt$. Of course this implies

$$\lVert f\rVert^2=\lVert f\rVert_2^2+\lVert f'\rVert_2^2$$

I want to show that the evaluation functional, i.e. the map $f\to f(x)$ is bounded for any $x$. The way I see it this basically comes down to saying that if $f$ and $f'$ have small $L_2$ norm, and $f$ is absolutely continuous, then $f$ must have small $L_\infty$ norm. Under normal circumstances information about $\lVert f\rVert_2$ tells you nothing about $\lVert f\rVert_\infty$, but here since $f$ is absolutely continuous it does: if $f(x)>y$, then we must have $f(x)>\frac y2$ on an neighborhood of $x$. Having a bound on $\lVert f'\rVert_2$ means that that neighborhood must be fairly wide since $f'$ can't be "too big". However, when I try to convert these intuitions into a proof, I feel like things get very convoluted very quickly. For example, I'm not even sure how to convert an upper bound on $\lVert f'\rVert_2$ into a lower bound for how wide that neighborhood must be.

This is Exercise 1.3 in *An introduction to the theory of reproducing kernel Hilbert spaces* by Paulsen and Raghupathi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\|f_n-f\|\to 0$ then $f_n(x)=\int_0^{x} f_n' (t)dt \to \int_0^{x}f'(t)dt=f(x)$. This is because $$| \int_0^{x} f'_n (t)dt -\int_0^{x}f'(t)dt|$$ $$=|\int_0^{x} [f'_n (t)-f'(t)]dt| \leq \int_0^{x} |f'_n (t)-f'(t)|dt$$ $$ \leq \int_0^{1} |f'_n (t)-f'(t)|dt\leq \|f'_n-f'\|_2$$ by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and $\|f'_n-f'\|_2 \leq \|f_n-f\|$.

Comment: So if we were to write this as a proof of boundedness rather than a proof of sequential continuity, what we would do is just write out the fundamental theorem of calculus, and from that get immediately (from Hölder) that $|f(x)|\leq\lVert f\rVert_2$? And then bounding by the norm of the exercise is just a sort of afterthought. So really, the norm introduced in the exercise is more complicated than it strictly needs to be for this particular result.

Comment: Well, the second term $\|f'\|_2$ alone would be enough for the proof to go through. @JackM

Comment: Yes, basically where I was going wrong was that I got distracted by trying to include the information about $\lVert f\rVert_2$. What I see now is that I should have zeroed-in on the fundamental property of a.c. functions that they're equal to the integral of their derivative.

Answer (score 0):

Since $f$ is absolutely continuous, clearly we have $$|f(x)|\le \int_0^x |f'(t)|dt$$
Now apply Jensen's inequality:
$$\left(\int_0^x |f'(t)|\frac{dt}{x}\right)^2\le \int_0^x |f'(t)|^2\frac{dt}{x}$$
We get$$
\left(\int_0^x |f'(t)|\right)^2\le x\int_0^x|f'(t)|^2dt\le \|f'\|_2^2$$
And so
$$|f(x)|\le\|f'\|_2$$